# PHP Laravel compare binary string with raw string

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, md5

I'm running php 7.4 on centos 7 with nginx, mysql

I got problem when i try to compare (md5 binary) string that queried from mysql (via eloquent) with the md5 binary string (use md5 function)

This is result i got from [Tinker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Roe5I.png)

```
Psy Shell v0.9.12 (PHP 7.4.30 ?cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> Users::findByName('test')->passwd2
[!] Aliasing 'Users' to 'App\Models\Users' for this Tinker session.
=> "冒IG\x06V?\x01\fB?`?\x08L\x15x"
>>> md5('testxxxxxxx',true)
=> b"冒IG\x06V?\x01\fB?`?\x08L\x15x"
>>> Users::findByName('test')->passwd2 == md5('testxxxxxxx',true)
=> false
```

But it works fine when i run it with apache (instead of nginx)
Am i miss any config or lib?

Comment: convert your md5 output into string and then compare like this

`Users::findByName('test')->passwd2 == (string) md5('testxxxxxxx',true)`

Comment: @PushkrajJori bad luck, still not work :'( result still in binary

Comment: Can you share your use case. So i can suggest different method to accomplish your goal?

Comment: @PushkrajJori in this case, after user register account, the password will be save into database with md5 binary method with type varchar length 64 (mysql) (required, no change, because other system use the same method, same database). And in login flow, i need to query the hashed password that saved from register flow compare with password that input by user

Comment: So you have one database sharing two different application and want to use one user on both applications? can you share the test case?